# [CRX]: didn't allow my js file in the extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

This is my application code:

The manifest.json file:

```
{
 "name": "YouTradeFx Debugger",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "This appliction allow YoutradeFX R&D team to debugging thier applications, by using few tools",
 "browser_action": {
   "default_popup": "app.html"
 }
}
```

The app.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Source of the application</title>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="width: 350px;">
  <span style="display: none;">
   <button id="Http">Send Requests</button>
    <button id="Cookie">Add Lead Params</button>
    <button id="Crm">CRM Faliure</button>
</span>
 <div id="Content">
 <table id="cons">
  <tr>
   <td>Please your username:</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="names" name="user"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="send" value="SEND"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The app.js file is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var HoldUser = $("input#names").val();
 $.get("https://www.mywebsite.com/ChromeExt/crm_buffer.php?uid="+HoldUser,function(data){
   $("div#cons").html(data);
 });

});
```

But I got the error message "**Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:**"." all the time..!

Why is not working? I did something wrong?

Comment: The error message is quite obious: You're using inline code somewhere. Does app.js or crm_buffer.php contain any inline code? Eg `onclick="foo();"` or `<script>...code...</script>`?

Comment: No, it just contains a string "hello world" that should be return...

Answer (score 0):

You are loading HTML (I assume) from `https://www.mywebsite.com/ChromeExt/crm_buffer.php?uid="+HoldUser` and then inject it in your `app.html` page. When HTML is injected it is parsed and all mentioned resources (`<script>`, `<link>`, `<object>`, `<img>` etc.) start to load. Since you probably have some JavaScript files there and since default Chrome Extension policy does not allow extensions to run scripts from remote locations you get an security violation error.

You can fix this by making response from your website more like API call, return JSON or text instead of HTML. If `mywebsite.com` isn't yours or you don't want to change anything there, you can whitelist scripts that it loads in [CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) or parse `data` variable returned in `$.get` and remove all `<script>` etc. before injecting it.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the page **https://www.mywebsite.com/ChromeExt/crm_buffer.php?uid="+HoldUser** so you may have click, mouse down, etc events on that page.  Also I don't see any permissions on **manifest.json**.  That too may be blocking the request.  You could easily test this by adding the lines below to **manifest.json**.  If that doesn't work, check mywebsite.com to see if that's broken.

```
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
],
```